# Deployment of app to device failed

Tags: xamarin, visual-studio-2017, xamarin-live-player

I have Xamarin Live Player up and running.

When I use it with a newly created Xamarin Forms (Master Details) app, it works fine. I see the app on the device.

However, when I try to run my full-blown app, Visual Studio tells me "Deployment to device failed. Make sure that Xamarin Live Player is open and that the device is in the same network."

Since the new app runs fine, I guess something else is the problem.
I've already set the Android project properties to be same as the newly created app.

Just to make sure, I've made it so that my full-blown app requests all rights.

How could I debug more in detail what's going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Xamarin Live Player can't run all apps. As soon as you use reflection, embedded resources, a MVVM framework or a custom renderer in Xamarin.Forms it might simply just not run the App.

You can read about the [limitations of Xamarin Live Player in the official documentation for it](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/tools/live-player/limitations?tabs=android).

You will probably have a much better experience just running directly on the device without Live Player.

Comment: Yep, I do all that. Thank you for the info!